# Pandas Frequency of subcategories in a GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame as shown below:

[image]

First I would like to get the overall frequencies of the `CODE` values, call it `FREQ`, then frequencies of the `CODE` values within each `AXLE` group and call it `GROUP_FREQ`.

I was able to calculate the `FREQ` column using the below code:

```
pivot = df[['AXLES','CODE']].pivot(['CODE']).agg(['count','mean','min','max'])
pivot['FREQ']=grouped_df.AXLES['count']/pivot.AXLES['count'].sum()*100`
```

this provides a nice grouped DataFrame as shown below:

[image]

However, I could not figure out how to calculate the frequencies within each `AXLE` group using this `grouped_by` DataFrame in the next step.

I tried:

```
pivot['GROUPFREQ']=pivot['AXLES','mean']['count']/pivot['AXLES','mean']['count'].sum()*100
```

However, this gives a `KeyError: 'count'`.

I may be on the wrong path, and what I am trying to achieve may not be done using `groupby`. I decided to check with the community after spending a couple of hours of trial and errors. I'd be glad if you could let me know what you think.

Thanks!

#### EDIT:

Reproducible input DataFrame:

```
,CODE,AXLES
0,0101,5
1,001,4
2,0110111,8
3,010111,7
4,0100,5
5,0101,5
6,0110111,8
7,00111,6
8,00111,6
9,0110111,8
10,0100,5
11,0110011,8
12,01011,6
13,0110111,8
14,0110111,8
15,011011,7
16,011011,7
17,011011,7
18,01011,6
19,01011,6
```

Desired Output for `pivot` DataFrame:

```
CODE,COUNT,AXLES,FREQ,GROUPFREQ
001,1,4,0.05,1.00
00111,2,6,0.1,0.40
0100,2,5,0.1,0.50
0101,2,5,0.1,0.50
01011,3,6,0.15,0.60
010111,1,7,0.05,0.25
0110011,1,8,0.05,0.17
011011,3,7,0.15,0.75
0110111,5,8,0.25,0.83
```

For the first line of the output:
001 is seen only once in the whole data set (20 records). Thus FREQ = 1/20 = 0.05
When the data is grouped by AXLES, for the AXLES=4 group, 001 is the only record, thus the GROUPFREQ = 1/1 = 1.00. (The same code cannot occur under various AXLE groups, so 001 only needs to be checked for AXLES=4.)

Comment: `df.CODE.value_counts()` & `df.groupby(['CODE', 'AXLES']).agg({'AXLES': 'count'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
pivot['FREQ'] = df.groupby('AXLES').CODE.value_counts(normalize=True).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```

Output:

```
       AXLES                   FREQ
       count mean min max          
CODE                               
1          1    4   4   4  1.000000
100        2    5   5   5  0.500000
101        2    5   5   5  0.500000
111        2    6   6   6  0.400000
1011       3    6   6   6  0.600000
10111      1    7   7   7  0.250000
11011      3    7   7   7  0.750000
110011     1    8   8   8  0.166667
110111     5    8   8   8  0.833333
```

Comment: This gives the overall frequencies for the whole DataFrame (which I also calculated). In a second step, I am trying to re-calculate the frequencies of CODES, this time **within** each `AXLE` group, and assign those values under a `GROUPFREQ` column.

Comment: What's your expected output from the sample data?

Comment: I added the expected output. The `FREQ` column gives frequencies of `CODE` values for the whole dataset. The `GROUPFREQ` column gives frequencies of `CODE` values **within** each `AXLES` group. (imagine you are slicing the input df as `df[df.AXLES==2]` (2 is an example) then calculating the frequencies, this needs to be repeated for all values of `AXLES` to populate the `GROUPFREQ` column.) E.g. the `CODE` `001` has a `FREQ` value of 0.05 (1 over 20 records), but a `GROUPFREQ` value of 1.00 (1 over 1 record, where `AXLE = 4`).

Comment: I  hope that clarified things a bit. `GROUPFREQ` is basically the occurrence frequencies of unique `CODE` records when we look at `AXLES` groups individually, as opposed to the whole set (which we calculated as `FREQ`).

Comment: @marillion see updated. You need to `groupby` on `AXLES`.